# AWS Oceania Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, amazon-route53

I'm wondering specifically what countries/IPs would resolve to Oceania in **Route53**. So, if a user in the **Philippines** loads 'www.abc.com' and we have geolocation rules for Asia and Oceania where would that user end up; likewise New Guinea and other countries in the Indian ocean that can deviate between **Australia/Asia/Oceania**.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The country codes are listed In [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-location):

> Oceania (OC): AS, AU, CK, FJ, FM, GU, KI, MH, MP, NC, NF, NR, NU, NZ, PF, PG, PN, PW, SB, TK, TL, TO, TV, UM, VU, WF, WS